# How can i return data from search activity?

Tags: java, android, search

I've got two activities:

1. Main(with all logic and fragments)
2. SearchActivity.

One of the Main's fragment calls getActivity().onSearchRequested().

SearchActivity catches the query and represents recived data in recycler.

Now I want to return selected item from recycler to that fragment, but I can't understand how to do that if startActivityForResult() wasn't called?

Comment: you want to close second activity on click and send data to first activity fragment?

Comment: @AntonKazakov, exactly

Comment: so you click your fragment's item then you call SearchActivity startActivity?

Comment: no, just method getActivity().onSearchRequested()
then activity starts by meta-data in manifest file